# Can't redirect or dispatch to another page in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying to implement a login system in my project but I can't get success yet. I'm using Tomcat 7, Java 6 and JSF 2.0 in my project, and always I try to redirect user to another page, I get a different error.

**Following is the relevant part of `login.xhtml`:**

```
<h:form id="form-login">
    <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login">Login:</label>
        <p:inputText styleClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="login" 
        placeholder="Nome de usuário" style="padding: 6px 12px;" required="true" 
        requiredMessage="Este campo é obrigatório." value="#{loginMBean.login}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="senha">Senha: </label>
        <p:inputText styleClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="senha"                                
                type="password" placeholder="Senha" style="padding: 6px 12px;" 
                required="true" requiredMessage="Este campo é obrigatório." 
                value="#{loginMBean.password}" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <h:commandButton value="Entrar" styleClass="btn btn-default btn-lg" 
                action="#{loginMBean.entrar}" />
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</h:form>
```

My `loginMBean`:

```
(String login, string password, this part is okay, already works)
...

public void entrar() throws IOException{

    Login loginTentativa = new Login(login, password);

    int resultadoValidacao = controle.validaLogin(loginTentativa);

    switch (resultadoValidacao) {
        case 0:
               FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("first/1-dados-escola.xhtml");
        case 1:                         
               FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/user/principal.xhtml");

        default:
            System.out.println("Usuário não autenticado.");
    }
}
```

Case 0: User authenticated, this is not the first time him access the website.
Case 1: user authenticated, this is the first time him access the website.
Case 2: not authenticated.

In my test, I have case 1. But, when I use **"redirect"**, I got the following error message:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:791)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1256)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

And when I try to use **"dispatch"**, I got:

```
 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:791)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1256)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

What I'm doing wrong? :/

Comment: You didn't use break statement in switch statement.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Ajeesh As I said, newbie error :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't use break statement inside switch so if after case 0 the case 1 will be executed and you will get the error "Cannot forward after response has been committed", try to return the url from this function,

```
 public String entrar() throws IOException{

Login loginTentativa = new Login(login, password);
 String result="";

int resultadoValidacao = controle.validaLogin(loginTentativa);

switch (resultadoValidacao) {
    case 0:
           result="first/1-dados-escola.xhtml";
    break;
    case 1:                         
           result="/user/principal.xhtml";
    break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Usuário não autenticado.");
}

return result;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this wooorkkss! Feeling a bastard now :S

Comment: Mistakes always improve ones knowledge

Comment: If you turn on all Java compiler warnings, the compiler will warn you about fall-through case statements.